# JW Player - event "onControlsShown"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I'm trying to build a small html menu that lies ontop of jwplayer and that should appear synchronously with the standard controls of JW Player (mousemove => fade in). Therefore, I've searched for the event that triggers the standard controls to show but so far I have not found anything working.

It's easy to bind a custom menu to an [event](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference/) like onVolume(), e.g. just add

```
events: {
    onVolume: function (event) {
        showMenu();
    }
},
```

to your embedding lines but ... what is the event that triggers standard controls to show?

Note: we use HDX Redirection and i'm not able to get any mouseevents with javascript that happen in the area of the player. With a "normal" client, I would just react to any mousemove. Thanks for any help!

Comment: We don't have an exact event for that, see - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference, starting with the "controls" section.

Comment: Hmm alright, I used a custom button and attached it to the menu. 
It's an HDX-Redirection thing, I guess... it works 100% on any normal client but with redirection active on our thin clients, it refuses.

Thanks for your answer, good support by JW Player team as always.

Comment: No problem, do you have any more information about HDX-Redirection?

Comment: "HDX MediaStream Flash Redirection allows you to move the processing  (flash rendering) of most Adobe Flash content from HVD VM to local  clients e.g 6215 thin client, or local computer with Citrix Receiver."

https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-29189

Anything but flash video comes from the server, e.g. the whole illusion of a local desktop & apps. 
If redirection is turned off  flash video is laggy because the traffic from server to client becomes too high. If redirection is active, flash video is smooth but events on the player dont work right.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about this.